# WARNING: dot command dot cannot be run

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz

I am working on documentation for a software. And i have used graphviz directive inside my rest file.

```
.. graphviz::
:align: center
```

However when i run

> make html

i get an error for dot command even though graphviz is installed in my virtenv (OS - mac). I have updated the conf.py to have the extension **'sphinx.ext.graphviz'**

WARNING: dot command ‘dot’ cannot be run (needed for graphviz output), check the graphviz_dot setting

Comment: Did you check [`graphviz_dot`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/graphviz.html#confval-graphviz_dot) as the message says?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be referred to an incorrect configuration of "dot" executable from GraphViz PATH.

See: https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse/pull/7230

On my windows machine, I solved it following these steps:

1. Check if the dot installation has been performed, going in the installation path (the default installation path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphvizX.XX\bin) and running here the command `dot.exe`
2. Go to Control Panel >  System and Security > System, and on the right side navigation panel, click the Advanced systems settings link.
3. In Advance settings, a dialogue box opens that shows the Environment Variables button. Click the button.
4. Select the entry Path in the system variables section and add C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphvizX.XX\bin to the existing path.

I think the problem could be solved on your OS machine just adding the PATH using the export command, such as:
`export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin`

Ref: https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GVIZ/pages/20971549/How+to+install+Graphviz+software
https://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sphinx can't find `dot` executable. Make sure it's in your path.