# Dot cannot be run in Pycharm with Sphinx and Graphviz

Tags: path, pycharm, python-sphinx, graphviz, dot

I am trying to create a class diagram with sphinx. For this I created a virtual environment in Pycharm and added this to conf.py:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc','sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram']
```

In my spamfilter.rst file I added the following lines:

```
Diagrams
=================
.. inheritance-diagram:: spamfilter
```

The output is not a diagram and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cfn6.png).

The following warning is displayed:

```
WARNING: dot command 'dot' cannot be run (needed for graphviz output), check the graphviz_dot setting
```

When I look into the folder *C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\documentation\venv\Lib\site-packages\graphviz*, there is a *dot.py* file, so I do not understand what is wrong. A similar question for Mac OS has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503855/warning-dot-command-dot-cannot-be-run). I tried the solution but it seems like it only works for Mac, because when I paste `export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin` to the Pycharm Terminal, it tells me that the command `export` could not be found. Honestly I have problems understanding why sometimes you can just use packages and other times they cannot be found even when they are installed, I am self-taught and a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

The "pip install graphviz" command installs a Python package that provides an interface to Graphviz (https://pypi.org/project/graphviz). This package is not required by Sphinx.

In order to create inheritance diagrams with Sphinx, the actual Graphviz toolkit (including dot.exe) must be installed. See https://www.graphviz.org.

If dot.exe is not in the PATH, you can use the [`graphviz_dot`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/graphviz.html#confval-graphviz_dot) configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where rendering a C4 model with PlantUML didn't work in the IDE (PyCharm 2022.2.1 Pro) on a newer M1 MacOS Monterey. I had it working on a Big Sur intel Mac prior to the upgrade with no extra effort, so the chip change caused me to go down a lot of paths with Rosetta and so on that were all unsuccessful.

The error was:

> Dot Executable: /opt/local/bin/dot
> File does not exist
> Cannot find Graphviz.

Graphviz *was* installed correctly, and `dot` was on my path, but it wasn't in `/opt/local/bin/dot`. Since it was in `/opt/homebrew/bin/dot`, all I needed to do was link the actual file with the path it was searching for:

```bash
cd /opt
sudo ln -s homebrew local
```

*et voilà*, PyCharm is now correctly rendering the puml in the IDE.