# sphinx-autoapi build error with sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram use Graphviz

Tags: python, python-sphinx, graphviz

I have the same problem as in the official documentation (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/inheritance.html#examples):

[image: error 1 screenshot]

My error is:

[image: error 2 screenshot]

Here is a part of my conf.py:

```
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.todo',
'sphinx.ext.coverage',
'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
'sphinx.ext.graphviz'
# 'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder']

extensions.append('autoapi.extension')
autoapi_type = 'python'
autoapi_dirs = ['../pyqpanda']
autoapi_options = ['members', 'undoc-members', 'private-members',
               'show-inheritance', 'show-module-summary',
               'special-members', 'imported-members', 'show-inheritance-diagram']

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['.templates']
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(rankdir="TB", size='""')
```

I use centos. Sphinx 5.1.1, Graphviz 0.2.

How to solve this abnormal information display? How to show the inherit_diagram in api reference?

Comment: Have you installed Graphviz (the actual toolkit, not just the https://pypi.org/project/graphviz Python wrapper)? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475981/407651

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557